# One of my websites stopped working without apparent reason. Help me figure out why?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, domain-name-system, vps, django

Hello I'm running unmanaged VPS at Hetzner with Ubuntu Linux. I use Apache to serve webpages and I have 8 websites on it. One particular website stopped responding without reason. Nobody touched anything on that VPS two days ago and it just stopped responding. The website is Django application with similar functionality as StackExchange (OSQA) and I use mod_wsgi to start this Django via apache. Apache logs don't show anything unusual and I suspect it is a DNS problem. When I try to ping the domain from the VPS I get the right IP:

```
root@genije:~# ping genije.org
PING genije.org (78.47.124.185) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from genije.org (78.47.124.185): icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=0.024 ms
64 bytes from genije.org (78.47.124.185): icmp_req=2 ttl=64 time=0.026 ms
```

But when I try to use w3m browser from VPS to GET the site I get "can't load genije.org". If I try to ping it from my home machine I get different IP:

```
C:\Users\Goran>ping www.genije.org

Pinging www.genije.org [67.215.66.132] with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
```

So this is why I believe it is a DNS problem. I use Namecheap for domain management with custom DNS servers. They were ns1.genije.org and ns2.genije.org. I just changed them to other ns1.itn.me and ns2.itn.me. Both of those servers point to the same IP. It is a mystery to me why this happen all of the sudden. Here's my DNS records file from VPS:

```
$ttl 38400
genije.org. IN  SOA ns1.itn.me. goran.itn.me. (
            1303520547
            10800
            3600
            604800
            38400 )
genije.org. IN  A   78.47.124.185
www.genije.org. IN  A   78.47.124.185
genije.org. IN  MX  5 ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
genije.org. IN  MX  5 ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
genije.org. IN  MX  10 ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.
genije.org. IN  MX  10 ASPMX3.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.
genije.org. IN  NS  ns1.genije.org.
genije.org. IN  NS  ns2.genije.org.
genije.org. IN  MX  1 ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
mail._domainkey IN TXT "v=DKIM1; g=*; k=rsa; t=y; p=STRINGGGG" ; ----- DKIM mail for genije.org
genije.org. IN  TXT v=spf1 a ptr ip4:78.47.124.185 mx:alt1.aspmx.l.google.com mx:alt2.aspmx.l.google.com mx:aspmx.l.google.com mx:aspmx2.googlemail.com mx:aspmx3.googlemail.com ?all
genije.org. IN  NS  genije.org.
genije.org. IN  NS  ns1.itn.me.
```

I just added last two NS lines in order to resolve the problem. Can anyone help me find the problem? Maybe my DNS suspicion is wrong, if so can you please point me in the right direction. I never had any similar problem so I don't know how to act. Thanks!

Goran

Comment: `1.` Copy successful site idea, down to look and feel. `2.` Hit stumbling block implementing it. `3.` Ask for help on the site that was ripped off. - Do you see the irony in this?

Comment: `One of my websites stopped working without apparent reason. Help me figure out why?`  Happily.  My fee is $100 an hour against an up-front commitment of $1000.  But Bart's probably right, that it's a DNS propagation issue.  If you're not using a tier 1 DNS provider, it can take up to 72 hours for DNS to fully propagate.  If it's still a problem after 3 days, contact me about my offer. :/

Comment: @MDMarra If I wanted to install a forum application and I hit stumbling block implementing it I shouldn't ask for help on other forums, right? So only stackexchange is allowed to use Q&A websites?

Answer (score 3):

Both www.genije.org & genije.org work fine. You should probably wait for the DNS to propagate.

Comment: I see but we haven't change any of the DNS information before it stopped working, that's what's baffling me.